# How to save BERT Huggingface Question Answer transformer pipeline as a reusable model

Tags: raspberry-pi, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I have written a Question/Answer BERT application that uses the transformer pipeline protocol.  I would like to port this to the Raspberry PI 4.  Is there a way to capture the complete cached  inference transformers pipeline model, quantize it, save it, and convert it to Tensorflow Lite model?  I want the user to be able to ask multiple ad hoc questions against the fine-tuned model.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check for [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

That's a practical way to encapsulate objects so you can save/export and import/load.

You can save your whole model / pipeline in a pickle file and load it in your Raspberry.

Comment: Thank you,  I will take a look at pickle...  I think that i have used it once before on a project.